# display combined records by months with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have got a challenge here, spent a few hours on making this happen but with no luck.
My data has got a product id and a timestamp. I have managed to combine data by product ids but also need to break these records by months (with timestamp help).

And at the moment it shows all records regardless a month but I want to achieve the view like this:

Product 1  |  Jan (2)  |  Feb ()  |  Mar (1)  |  Apr ()  | etc 
Product 2  |  Jan ()   |  Feb (2) |  Mar ()   |  Apr (3) | etc

the jquery code I use is:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var obj ={};
$.each($('.single-record .product'), function(index, item) {
    var record = $(item).data('record');
    if ($('#product-id-'+record).length > 0) obj[record] = $('div[data-record="'+record+'"]').length;
});
$.each(obj,function(i, el){
    $('#product-id-'+i).append('<span>' + el + '</span>');
});
});
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Please feel free to edit my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4zxV/

Comment: I'm not clear what you want to do, here.

Comment: Hi Jimmy, I want to display records by months and category. For example 2 products were issued in October. In my HTML code I can only get a div with id of category and it's timestamp.

Comment: So I want to combine and put these records into appropriate field. Hope it does make sense now.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the DOM to grab this data? Wouldn't it be easier if your server just outputted a JSON your JS could simply use? Then you could keep your view and model completely separate.

Comment: I am afraid this is only what I have got to work with. Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you, at the very least, initialize your JS by parsing the DOM for the data, then keep the records as javascript objects later functions can just read? I would suggest this could help minimize the amount of DOM parsing you do.

Comment: Let me apologise Jimmy, it seems you speak a different language to me. I am not a programmer sorry for being stupid cow.

Comment: I don't think you're stupid, but it does look like you're doing things the hard way rather than the right way. Is there a more experienced front-end developer who can work with you on this task?

Comment: I would handle it in the DB/server side code...

Comment: at them moment I haven't got any budget for hiring a developer. So trying to do it by myself for a charity project. I know it is not easy task to play with data in html especially combining and grouping it.

Comment: Thank you Miller, at the moment I have got only this HTML output from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var months = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
    var productMonthMappings = [];

    $.each($('.single-record .product'), function(index, item) {
        // get productId
        var productId = $(item).data('record');

        // Create month mappings for this product if not existent
        if (typeof productMonthMappings[productId] === 'undefined' 
            || productMonthMappings[productId] === null) {
            productMonthMappings[productId] = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                // Set initial count to 0
                productMonthMappings[productId][i] = 0;
            }
        }

        // Parse the date and get the month for the current record
        var date = new Date(1000 * $(item).next().html());
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var monthName = months[month];

        // Increment the count for that date for the product
        productMonthMappings[productId][month]++;
    });

    // Print counts per month
    $.each(productMonthMappings, function(i, productMonthMapping){
        if (productMonthMapping !== undefined
            && productMonthMapping !== null
            && $('#product-id-'+i).length > 0) {
                $.each(productMonthMapping, function(j, count){
                    if (count === undefined || count === null) {
                        count = 0;
                    }

                    $('#product-id-'+i).append(
                        ' | ' + months[j] + '(' + count + ')'
                    );
                });
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjyb8/

Comment: Thanks a lot Mayabelle. You're genius.

Answer (score 1):

Few modification of your code and i think it works,

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var obj = {};
    $.each($('.single-record .product'), function (index, item) {
        var record = $(item).data('record');
        if ($('#product-id-' + record).length > 0) {
            var dateMillis=parseFloat($(item).next('.date').text().trim());
            console.log(dateMillis);
            console.log(new Date(dateMillis));
            var month = new Date(dateMillis).getMonth();
            console.log(month);
            if(obj[record]==undefined){obj[record]=[];}
            if(obj[record][month]==undefined){
                obj[record][month]=1;
            }else{
                ++obj[record][month];
            }
            console.log("record:"+record+" month:"+month+"  - "+obj[record][month]);
        }
    });
    $.each(obj, function (i, el) {
        $prdEl = $('#product-id-' + i);
        el.forEach(function(n,month){
            $prdEl.append('<span>' +getMonthName(month) +'('+ el[month] + ')</span>');
        });
    });
});

function getMonthName(index) {
    var month = new Array();
    month[0] = "January";
    month[1] = "February";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "October";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "December";
    return month[index];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b4zxV/3/

Comment: Hi Melc, amazing example of the unique approach. Thank you very much. Your code is working brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear on what you're trying to do but this sounds like a task for jQuery $.map(). If you have jQuery 1.6 or greater, try using jQuery Map to get the collections you want similar to below:

```
var byMonth = $.map($('.single-record .product'), function(val) {
 //check the value against the month or something
  if(val.find('.date').text() =='whatever you want') {
    months.push(......);
    return val;
  }
});
```

byMonth will contain an array of all objects that meet your criteria. You could also push to arrays withing the callback function or modify objects, etc, whatever suits your overall goals.

JQuery map iterates over an array or object and performs an action on each value and also returns an array of the modified values. It's useful for converting array-like objects to arrays, but also for something similar to what you're trying to achieve.

See the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: Thank you for the tip Jazzuzz.